# vuetify autocomplete preload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

i'm learning vuetify framework, i managed to use most of the components but i have a problem with autocomplete component.
Using it from scratch works fine, bug if i try to set value during creation it doesn't work at all.
I tried to extend one of the vuetify example but without success.

i would like to load first value from the API during creation but it stays empty.

Thanks for your help.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    descriptionLimit: 60,
    entries: [],
    isLoading: false,
    model: null,
    search: "Cats"
  }),
 created :function() {
  model={"API":"Cats","Description":"Pictures of cats from Tumblr","Auth":"","HTTPS":true,"Cors":"unknown","Link":"https://thecatapi.com/docs.html","Category":"Animals"},
   search="Cats"
},
  computed: {
    fields () {
      if (!this.model) return []

      return Object.keys(this.model).map(key => {
        return {
          key: key,
          value: this.model[key] || 'n/a'
        }
      })
    },
    items () {
      return this.entries.map(entry => {
        const Description = entry.Description.length > this.descriptionLimit
          ? entry.Description.slice(0, this.descriptionLimit) + '...'
          : entry.Description

        return Object.assign({}, entry, { Description })
      })
    }
  },

  watch: {
    search (val) {
      // Items have already been loaded
      if (this.items.length > 0) return

      this.isLoading = true
      console.log("loadgin data")
      // Lazily load input items
      axios.get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries')
        .then(res => {
          const { count, entries } = res.data
          this.count = count
          this.entries = entries
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
        .finally(() => (this.isLoading = false))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
      color="red lighten-2"
      dark
    >
      <v-card-title class="headline red lighten-3">
        Search for Public APIs
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        Explore hundreds of free API's ready for consumption! For more information visit
        <a
          class="grey--text text--lighten-3"
          href="https://github.com/toddmotto/public-apis"
          target="_blank"
        >the Github repository</a>.
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-autocomplete
          v-model="model"
          :items="items"
          :loading="isLoading"
          :search-input.sync="search"
          color="white"
          hide-no-data
          hide-selected
          item-text="Description"
          item-value="API"
          label="Public APIs"
          placeholder="Start typing to Search"
          prepend-icon="mdi-database-search"
          return-object
        ></v-autocomplete>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      <v-expand-transition>
        <v-list v-if="model" class="red lighten-3">
          <v-list-tile
            v-for="(field, i) in fields"
            :key="i"
          >
            <v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-title v-text="field.value"></v-list-tile-title>
              <v-list-tile-sub-title v-text="field.key"></v-list-tile-sub-title>
            </v-list-tile-content>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
      </v-expand-transition>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn
          :disabled="!model"
          color="grey darken-3"
          @click="model = null"
        >
          Clear
          <v-icon right>mdi-close-circle</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the code you are trying to use then you are missing a ',' at the end of the "model".

```
created :function() { 
  model={...}, <----
  search="Cats"
},
```

Comment: Thanks, my bad i was updating my code before posting here. i'll update the question but it not enough

Answer (score 0):

blalan05 on the discrod channel just give me the reply : my created function was garbled.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    descriptionLimit: 60,
    entries: [],
    isLoading: false,
    model: null,
    search: "Cats"
  }),
 created () {
  this.model = {"API":"Cats","Description":"Pictures of cats from Tumblr","Auth":"","HTTPS":true,"Cors":"unknown","Link":"https://thecatapi.com/docs.html","Category":"Animals"},
   this.search = "Cats"
},
  computed: {
    fields () {
      if (!this.model) return []

      return Object.keys(this.model).map(key => {
        return {
          key: key,
          value: this.model[key] || 'n/a'
        }
      })
    },
    items () {
      return this.entries.map(entry => {
        const Description = entry.Description.length > this.descriptionLimit
          ? entry.Description.slice(0, this.descriptionLimit) + '...'
          : entry.Description

        return Object.assign({}, entry, { Description })
      })
    }
  },

  watch: {
    search (val) {
      // Items have already been loaded
      if (this.items.length > 0) return

      this.isLoading = true
      console.log("loadgin data")
      // Lazily load input items
      axios.get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries')
        .then(res => {
          const { count, entries } = res.data
          this.count = count
          this.entries = entries
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
        .finally(() => (this.isLoading = false))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
      color="red lighten-2"
      dark
    >
      <v-card-title class="headline red lighten-3">
        Search for Public APIssss
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        Explore hundreds of free API's ready for consumption! For more information visit
        <a
          class="grey--text text--lighten-3"
          href="https://github.com/toddmotto/public-apis"
          target="_blank"
        >the Github repositoryyy</a>.
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-autocomplete
          v-model="model"
          :items="items"
          :loading="isLoading"
          :search-input.sync="search"
          color="white"
          hide-no-data
          hide-selected
          item-text="Description"
          item-value="API"
          label="Public APIs"
          placeholder="Start typing to Search"
          prepend-icon="mdi-database-search"
          return-object
        ></v-autocomplete>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      <v-expand-transition>
        <v-list v-if="model" class="red lighten-3">
          <v-list-tile
            v-for="(field, i) in fields"
            :key="i"
          >
            <v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-title v-text="field.value"></v-list-tile-title>
              <v-list-tile-sub-title v-text="field.key"></v-list-tile-sub-title>
            </v-list-tile-content>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
      </v-expand-transition>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn
          :disabled="!model"
          color="grey darken-3"
          @click="model = null"
        >
          Clear
          <v-icon right>mdi-close-circle</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```